# IOexception when connecting to REST Service SDK25+

Tags: android, json, http

So I am trying to read JSON from a REST API; however, I keep getting an IOException when trying to use Scanner to read the JSON.

The goal, is to read all the JSON from the API, and output it to Logcat.

After running the Debugger, the exception is thrown at "InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();"

"IsConnected" Is also returning as false, so I am wondering if this may be a firewall issue as well; however, I don't think thats the case.

I am required to use API25 and higher.

Is there something noticeably wrong that I am doing?

I am a student, and would prefer a small explanation, instead of just a quick code fix! Thank you!

Edit: 
Added stackTrace below code.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(isConnected()) {
            Log.i("Status", "Connected");
            WebAsyncTask task = new WebAsyncTask();

            task.execute("http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all");
        }else {
            Log.i("Status", "Not Connected");
        }

    }

    public boolean isConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}

class WebAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
          //  Log.i("URL",url.toString());
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                builder.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            String data = builder.toString();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Message[] msg = gson.fromJson(data,Message[].class);
            for (int i=1;i<msg.length;i++){
              //  publishProgress(msg[i].getMessage()+"\n");
                Log.i("values", msg[i].getMessage()+"\n");
        }
        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            publishProgress("URL PROBLEM");
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            publishProgress("Input Problem");

        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values){
        super.onProgressUpdate();
        Log.i("values", values[0]+"\n");
    }
}
class Message{
    int status;
    String message;
    int junk;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getJunk() {
        return junk;
    }
}


03-27 10:53:46.733 31032-31047/? W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "services.groupkt.com": No address associated with hostname
03-27 10:53:46.734 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:125)
03-27 10:53:46.734 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
03-27 10:53:46.734 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
03-27 10:53:46.735 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
03-27 10:53:46.735 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
03-27 10:53:46.735 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
03-27 10:53:46.735 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
03-27 10:53:46.735 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:345)
03-27 10:53:46.735 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
03-27 10:53:46.735 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
03-27 10:53:46.736 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
03-27 10:53:46.736 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
03-27 10:53:46.736 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
03-27 10:53:46.737 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at ca.on.sl.comp208.lhahncomp208a3m1.WebAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:59)
03-27 10:53:46.737 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at ca.on.sl.comp208.lhahncomp208a3m1.WebAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:51)
03-27 10:53:46.737 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
03-27 10:53:46.737 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-27 10:53:46.737 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
03-27 10:53:46.737 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
03-27 10:53:46.737 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
03-27 10:53:46.737 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
03-27 10:53:46.738 31032-31047/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
03-27 10:53:46.738 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
03-27 10:53:46.738 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
03-27 10:53:46.738 31032-31047/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:106)
```

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace of the error you're seeing? That could help in debugging.

Comment: Have you added the internet permission? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @WoogieNoogie I added the Stack trace, saying "Unable to resolve Host" - Going to the address works as intended.

Comment: @JisuHong I have added the permissions to the Manifest.Xml file

Comment: what kind of exception is thrown at inputstream?

Comment: @JisuHong an IOException

Comment: add run time permission into your code

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same issue. From your stack trace you got

> 03-27 10:53:46.733 31032-31047/? W/System.err:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
>   "services.groupkt.com": No address associated with hostname

And that seems to have a wrong base URL which I could solve by replacing below from your code

```
task.execute("http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all");
```

into

```
task.execute("http://groupkt.com/country/get/all");
```